# Loops in Pentaho - is this transformation looping?

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

Is the following transformation looping through each of the rows in the applications field?

Also is there a way to loop through and output each individual row to it's own txt or excel file (preferably txt).

At the moment it outputs all rows to the one text file. I want to do this without creating multiple text file transformations. 
Unsure if a switch case would be a loop.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformations by their very nature apply the steps to all the rows in them. It's probably a good idea to familiarize yourself a bit more with the flow-based concept, then you can answer the switch/case question for yourself.

Regarding one file per row, you can use the option "Accept filename from field" in the Text File Output step and then put your Applications field there. You will need to add the destination path in a prior step, since PDI expects the full path and filename in that field.

Comment: thank you, but how would i go about adding the destination path? I'm unsure which step to use to do so

Comment: Add Constants or Get Variable or even take it from the input file step. Then you use Concat Fields with no separator to put them together. You can even start with something like "/my/path/subfolder/DUMMY_something" and use Replace In String to replace DUMMY with your application name if you want stuff after the application too.